# Keep service running when the app is killed

Tags: android, android-service

How can I keep the service running when the app is killed?

App 1: When I pressing on the recent apps key on the phone and close the app, Then the app stops the service and starts it again.

App 2: When I pressing on the recent apps key on the phone and close the app, Then the app not stops the service and continues working.

How can I make my service like App 2?

**Manifest**

```
<service android:name=".WindowManagerService" />
```

**WindowManagerService**

> onStartCommand is empty but it return START_STICKY

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for:
[background processing](https://developer.android.com/guide/background)

or for older versions: [background service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service)

Comment: I want to use WindowManager but I should use background or foreground?

Comment: I think it depends on the task you want to run in background. If the user wants to close an app fast forward i think there is no easy way to run it nevertheless.